# Problems with a fixed navigation bar and Bootstrap's scrollspy

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I'm trying to create a fixed navigation bar on the left of a site using Bootstrap. This is the site: [link](http://so.l3r.de/index.html)

The scrollspy seems to work but the nav div seems to be underneath the Bootstrap containers (visible when scrolling the page, the white line separating the sections seems to be on top of the navigation bar). Also the navigation items aren't clickable.
How can I fix my navigation bar? Is it's placement outside the Bootstrap grid the problem (sadly I don't know a different solution as I use containers and rows for the separated sections of the site)?

Thanks in advance for the help and I hope the CSS isn't too bad O:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to scrollspy menu:

```
.scrollspy {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```